# Optimal way data set columns from multple tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

i am trying to fine tune a query which runs on application dashboard.

Query is like i have a master table & few transaction tables. I have to make some calculation on transataion table & showcase same output along  with few columns from the master table.

I tried with join that worked but query is not fast enough for application ( 40Sec for 1k Records).

I am trying with sub query but maybe i am making mistake somewhere.

sharing dummy details below.

Master  table :

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Cell1 |
| 2 | Cell2 |
| 3 | Cell3 |
| 4 | Cell4 |

transaction table 1 Session1

```
| id  | TotalMarks |
| 1   | 21   | 
| 1   | 21   |
| 2   | 23   |
| 3   | 24   |
```

Transaction table 2 Session2

```
| id  | TotalMarks |
| 1   | 22   | 
| 2   | 28   |
| 4   | 25   |
| 4   | 29   |
```

Result i want Like

```
| id  | Name | ObtainMarksSession1 | totalObtainMarkSession2 |
| 1   | cell1 |  

               |                         |
```

I have checked indexes already but anyway index won't help as i am using aggregate function.

join query

```
Select m.id,m.name,sum(s1.TotalMarks) ObtainMarksSession1, sum(s1.TotalMarks) ObtainMarksSession2 
from master join session1 s1 on m.id=s1.id and s1.id is not null 
join session2 s2 on m.id=s2.id and s2.id is not null 
group by m.id,m.name;
```

subquery Sample

```
Select id, sum(TotalMarks) ObtainMarksSession1 from session1 where id is not null;
```

Same way i got result from other table also but now i am unable to merge both output. these single query output are very fast.

Need to know how to merge result & get output with name as well from master. also, other suggestion if i can try some other method to make this query fast.

P.s Id is not primary key in transaction table so there might be possiblity for null values.

Comment: I guess s1 is a typo here -sum(s1.TotalMarks) ObtainMarksSession2 Also inner joins only fetch matched records so and s1.id is not null is pointless.

Comment: Got it. I tried with first left join then i put this query & got the result in proper way with is not null condtion but when i tried with inner join /Join & removed is not null & i didn't get the proper result . It multiplied with both resultset s1 & s2 id & got duplicate entries.